# How to change font size of SelectField for wtforms in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a SelectField in my Flask Application. How do I change the font size of the options in the SelectField?

I have referenced [Wtforms form field text enlargement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749364/wtforms-form-field-text-enlargement) but the field is TextAreaField so I'm not sure how to alter the SelectField.

Comment: One option is to use the CSS and change the font size as per you needs.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha how do you add a class or id onto a form field?

Comment: you can use like this : {{ form.name(class_="form-control",size=120) }}